# RoutingError with glyphicon rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glyphicons

I use this [gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) for bootsrap, but glyphicon doesn't shows. And I get this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff"):
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf"):

I try to craete folders with fonts in my assets, but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for this would be to place the files in the public directory of your app.  In your case it would be:
`(Rails_app)/public/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff`
`(Rails_app)/public/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`
Public file is the root of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I uses the steps below to resolve the problem:

1. Manually download the bootstrap package as zip from the github site: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
2. Upload then unzip the package in the production server /tmp folder
3. Manually create a folder under %approot/public/assets/twitter/fonts
4. Copy 'bootstrap-master/fonts/*' to the above folder
5. RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
6. Restart the rails server(s)

Comment: There is no folder like you have described  'bootstrap-master/fonts/*'  inside git repo